# How to find a web element in selenium that contains a text using python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to find a web element that contains text 'My' .But the text is stored in a variable named msg

msg = "My"

How do I use the variable in the xpath and find the web element . I also want to click the element

below code works if I give the text directly in the xpath . But i want to use the variable msg to generalize

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'My')]")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '{}')]".format(msg))
```

Just use format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use text equals as well:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='{}']".format("you_text"))
```

but I agree, contains is more flexible:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'{}')]".format("you_text"))
```